# Get All Emails with Google Python API CLient

Tags: python, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to get all user emails with the quickstart script provided by google at : [this link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)

I see that the API supports `q` parameter for querying a specific time frame. But I need data of the entire inbox.

The response I get is only the messages from Page 1. I however need all the messages from my inbox. Is there a way to get contents of the entire inbox?

Currently I have

```
today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(1)

query = "before: {0} after: {1}".format(today.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'),
                                        yesterday.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=query).execute()
```

Comment: You need to process the `nextPageToken` https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#list

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of messages you can obtain in a Messages.List request is 511, so you can set this value to the 'maxResults' parameter in the request. To obtain the next messages results, you need to use the 'nextPageToken' value as a parameter in the subsequent request [1].

I implemented this code to print the sets of messages results each separated by a line break.

```
today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(1)

query = "before: {0} after: {1}".format(today.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'),
                                        yesterday.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=query, maxResults=511).execute()
print(results)
print("\n")

pageToken = None
if 'nextPageToken' in results:
    pageToken = results['nextPageToken']

while pageToken:
    results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=query, maxResults=511, pageToken=pageToken).execute()
    print(results)
    print("\n")
    if 'nextPageToken' in results:
        pageToken = results['nextPageToken']
    else:
        break

 print("No more messages")
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

Comment: Thank you @andres-duarte for the answer! Is there also any elegant way to batch these? 
I see that the Google API will no longer support batch requests to the HTTP endpoint as per [this link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch)

Comment: You can make batch requests, but in this case doesn't have much sense because you need the response from the first request to make the subsequent requests. In a batch request all the requests are sent at the same time.